# How do i rename a scripted field in kibana?

Tags: kibana-4

Is there a way i can change only the name of a scripted field? I'm using Kibana 4.3.0. For eg. I want to rename Bytes Read(GB) to Bytes Read. When i click on edit field, it doesn't allow name changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not change the name of a scripted field, you only can copy the script and paste in a new scripted field with the new name.

Comment: Do you know the reason why we can't?

Comment: Because when you do graph using the new scripted field you can find problem when you change the name of the new field, for that in kibana you can not change names of fields or scripted field, because you can bug all your dashboard.

Comment: :) I thought the change would get updated wherever required.

Comment: Yes, but Kibana need a lot of improvements, as change color in graph, i have read that in following version you could customize the graph.